# How can I write a DNF to CNF form?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How can I have write (p∧q) ∨ (¬p ∧ ¬q), which is the equivalent for (p<->q), in conjunctive normal form (CNF)?

In general, am I allowed to do (p ∨ (¬p ∧ ¬q)) ∧ (q ∨ (¬p ∧ ¬q)) ??

Comment: No, what you have is not CNF.  If you have $(a \wedge b) \vee (c)$ then you can "distribute" as $(a\vee c) \wedge (b \vee c)$.  In your case you have $(a\wedge b) \vee (c \wedge d)$ which then becomes $\big(a \vee (c\wedge d)\big) \wedge \big(b \vee (c \wedge d)\big)$, which then can become $\big((a \vee c) \wedge (a \vee d)\big) \wedge \big((b \vee c) \wedge (b \vee d)\big)$, from here we should be able to show that this is equivalent to $(a \vee c) \wedge (a \vee d) \wedge (b \vee c) \wedge (b \vee d)$ (I believe).  Your's will simplify since you will get things like $p \vee \neg p$.

Comment: So if I continue (p ∨ (¬p ∧ ¬q)) ∧ (q ∨ (¬p ∧ ¬q)) as

( (p ∨ ¬p) ∧ (p ∨ ¬q) ) ∧  ( (q ∨ ¬p) ∧ (q ∨ ¬q) ) 

then (p ∨ ¬p) ∧ (p ∨ ¬q)  ∧  (q ∨ ¬p) ∧ (q ∨ ¬q)  is the final form?

Comment: And how does  p∨¬p simplify? :D

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, just keep going:

\begin{align}
(p\wedge q) \vee (\neg p \wedge \neg q) =&\ \big(p \vee (\neg p \wedge \neg q)\big) \wedge \big(q \vee (\neg p \wedge \neg q\big) \\
=&\ \big((p \vee \neg p) \wedge (p \vee \neg q)\big) \wedge \big((q \vee \neg p) \wedge (q \vee \neg q)\big) \\
=&\ (p \vee \neg p) \wedge (p \vee \neg q) \wedge (q \vee \neg p) \wedge (q \vee \neg q)
\end{align}

If you are uneasy about that last step, taking away the parentheses, then I believe it can be shown to be true through the associative property of the $\wedge$ operator.  That is $(a \wedge b) \wedge c \equiv a \wedge (b \wedge c)$.

However $\zeta \vee \neg \zeta$ is a tautology...every boolean value is either true or false, therefore $p \vee \neg p$ and $q \vee \neg q$ are trivially true and can be dropped out of the CNF form leaving only:

$$
(p \vee \neg q) \wedge (\neg p \vee q)
$$

This makes sense if you think about it.  If $p$ is true then $\neg p$ is false, therefore, to be true $q$ must be true to satisfy this property.  Thus $p \rightarrow q$.  Also if $\neg p$ is true, then $\neg q$ must be true to satisfy the above, thus $\neg p \rightarrow \neg q$.  Together, these are the double implication.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Do you mind also checking this one? How can I simplify it? (the answer on wolframalpha is p ^ q ^ -r )    

 ¬((p∧q) -> (q ∧ r))  =   ¬(¬(p∧q) ∨ (q ∧ r)) = ((p∧q) ∧ (¬q  ∨ ¬r)) How should i continue?

Answer (score 1):

> In general, am I allowed to do $(p ∨ (¬p ∧ ¬q)) ∧ (q ∨ (¬p ∧ ¬q))$

Yes, we can.   That is an application of *distribution*.   Only we don't stop here: were not CNF yet.

We can do it again on the first factor:  $((p ∨ ¬p) ∧ (p ∨ ¬q)) ∧ (q ∨ (¬p ∧ ¬q))$

But wait: there's a tautology: $(p∨\neg p)$, which can be absorbed (by conjunctive identity).

So we have: $(p∨\neg q)\wedge(q\vee(\neg p\wedge \neg q))$

Keep going until you have conjunctions of disjunctions of atomic propositions.